# boost zip_iterator ignoring const correctness

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

In the for loop inside the `main()` function of the following code, I can change the variables inside the variable `ab` even when the `const auto&` is used in the loop. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass {
  std::vector<int> a{11, 21, 41};
  std::vector<int> b{1, 2, 4};
  typedef boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuple<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>> const_iterator;
  typedef boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuple<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>> iterator;

  const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.cbegin(), b.cbegin()));
  }
  const_iterator end() const {
    return const_iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.cend(), b.cend()));
  }
  iterator begin() {
    return iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.begin(), b.begin()));
  }
  iterator end() {
    return iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.end(), b.end()));
  }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
  MyClass myc;
  for (const auto &ab: myc)
    ab.get<0>() = 66;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no way it will know what you're storing these into. `myc` is non-const, so the tuple will contain non-const iterators. It's up to the tuple type to make `get` return something non-modifiable when used with a const tuple of references. It would have to go out of its way because `const T&` when `T` is a non-const reference collapses to the same non-const reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over a `const MyClass` then you will get the compile error you desire:

```
for (const auto &ab: const_cast<MyClass const&>(myc))
    ab.get<0>() = 66;
```

You can use `std::as_const` instead of the `const_cast`:

```
for (const auto &ab: std::as_const(myc))
    ab.get<0>() = 66;
```

This works because the `const` overloads of `begin` and `end` will be called instead, and they return a `zip_iterator` of const iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `myc` is not const, so you are iterating through it with a `myc::iterator`, not a `myc::const_iterator`.

You then bind `ab` to the result of indirecting through that iterator.  `ab.get<0>`() will be a const method (because it doesn't change `ab`), but it returns a reference to a *non*-const int.

The solution is to use `std::as_const(myc)` (where you won't even need the `const` on the declaration of `ab`).

```
for (auto &ab: std::as_const(myc))
    ab.get<0>() = 66;  // Error.  Cannot write to const object.
```